# Adding new network interface causes DNS Resolution failed

Tags: dns, network-interface

I'm using raspberry pi with raspbian OS. I've a wireless network. It works without any problem but after I added new network interface using ppp connection, it seems that something is wrong with DNS settings.

Before adding new ppp0 interface, I was able to ping to both 8.8.8.8 and [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). After adding ppp0 interface (by `sudo pon rnet`), ppp0 interface is listed and got IP address.
I can ping to 8.8.8.8 via both wlan0 and ppp0. `ping -I ppp0 8.8.8.8`, `ping -I wlan0 8.8.8.8` both work but `ping -I ppp0 www.google.com` doesn't work and `ping -I wlan0 www.google.com` doesn't work anymore.

I'm sharing returns of `cat /etc/resolve.conf` before and after ppp0 added.

before:

```
nameserver 192.168.31.1
```

after:

```
nameserver 213.74.0.4
nameserver 213.74.1.4
nameserver 192.168.31.1
```

Comment: Is your defaultroute set to ppp0 interface? does wlan0 connect to the same provider? the new DNS-servers seem to only react to their customers. You can also try `nslookup www.google.com 192.168.31.1`. Does that resolve?

Comment: You could have added the result of the `ip route` and `route` command to help identifying the issue.